# How to relate a table to another table that already has a relationship (N:N)?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I am having some difficulty to understand the follow relationship. I have three entities, brand, segment and product. One brand can has many segment and one segment can be in many brand. One product can has one segment and one segment can has many product. I don't understand how I can associate the product entity with segment. The goal is to get a product and identify what is your segment and brand.

1 Brand: N Segments

1 Segment: N Brands

1 Product: 1 Segment

1 Segment: N Products

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a N:M relationship between brands and segments. One typical solution would be to create a bridge tables between tables `brands` and `segments`. Assuming that table `brands` has primary key `brand_id` and `segments` has primary key `segment_id`, you can create a third table called `brand_segments`, with columns `brand_id` and `segment_id`, to represent the relation.

On the other hand, the relation between segments and products is 1:N. You could represent this by adding a column in the `products` table that stores a reference to the id of the segment it belongs to.

Sample schema

```
brands
    brand_id
    brand_name

segments
    segment_id
    segment_name

products
    product_id
    product_name
    segment_id

brand_segments
    brand_id
    segment_id
```

Query to recover all segments associated to a product:

```
SELECT p.*, s.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN segments s ON s.segment_id = p.segment_id
```

Query to recover all brands associated to a product:

```
SELECT p.*, b.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN brand_segments bs ON bs.segment_id = p.segment_id
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.brand_id = bs.brand_id
```

Both queries combined

```
SELECT p.*, s.*, b.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN segments s ON s.segment_id = p.segment_id
INNER JOIN brand_segments bs ON bs.segment_id = p.segment_id
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.brand_id = bs.brand_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would be how you could join them and retreive related data.

```
SELECT seg.Segment, prd.Product, brn.Brand
FROM Segment seg
LEFT JOIN Brand brn on brd.ID = seg.ID
LEFT JOIN Product prd on prd.ID = seg.ID
```

The ID fields are your primary and foreign keys.